# Gitlab CI - Docker in Docker - How to maintain a pipeline?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am trying to use gitlab CI for docker in docker builds and i have it up and running.
My issue is that the nice pipeline functionality of gitlab is somewhat lost since the whole build,test,etc... stages are defined in the DockerFile and not yaml.
I only have a single stage in the yaml right now.

Is there a way to use docker in docker and still leverage gitlab pipelines?

Relevant files.
Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1 - require and update image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.0 AS build
# Update the imgage OS 
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y
# set the container working directory
WORKDIR /code

# Stage 2 - copy data
# caches restore result by copying csproj file separately
COPY src/Nuget.Config ./src/

COPY src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.csproj ./src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader/ 
RUN dotnet restore src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.csproj --configfile /code/src/Nuget.Config

COPY src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test.csproj ./src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test/ 
RUN dotnet restore src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test.csproj --configfile /code/src/Nuget.Config

# Copy the rest
COPY . .

# Stage 3 - Build and test
RUN dotnet test src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.Test.csproj

# Stage 4 - Deploym to image
RUN dotnet publish src/Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader --output /code/output --configuration Release

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.0

COPY --from=build /code/output /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Inflow.NewsMl.FileLoader.dll" ]
```

and the ci runner yaml

```
image: docker:latest

.before_script:
  - docker info

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: infomedia/newsml.fileloader:CI_COMMIT_SHA
  #$CI_COMMIT_TAG

services:
- docker:dind

stages:
- build

build:
  stage: build
  #only:
  #  - tags
  #except:
  #  - master
  script:
  - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
```

Comment: The pipeline is not just to execute your build. Check their AutoDeploy yaml file and you will see what else you can do. Basically, the build step will publish your container and the next step could be using it in integration tests and they going to a review app stage and then to production.